# How to set env variable for all process?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I'm working on Linux,

Can anybody please help me to set a env variable on Linux that will be available for all process running on the same machine?

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the definition of your env variable into /etc/profile :

`VARIABLE=content`

If that doesn't work, you could try /etc/environment

Comment: That won't reach all processes, only those started from a users shell.

Comment: I added /etc/environment

Comment: Sounds better, though it depends on the PAM configuration. I wonder if it is possible to hand that environment variable to the init process. All other processes are started by that one, so they all inherit that variable.